# find the firmware in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, firmware

I am looking for a way to find the os version and model version of the computer my site is being viewed on.
jQuery, javascript, html, php, asp...
Any language browsers generally support will do.
I know it's possible, comex did it for iOS.
I think he did:

```
firmware.indexof("4.0");
```

But I need the model too, as I said before. That is a *veeeeeerrrrrryyyyyy* long script that won't work for me anyway.
I [googled](http://www.google.com/search?q=find+device+firmware+javascript&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari)
 it, but no luck.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I know it's possible, comex did it for iOS." – this does not imply it's possible for anything except iOS. Generally speaking, I really really hope the information you want is *not* available to webpages; consequently, I don't think browsers will let you find it out.

Comment: Sorry did not read rest of question. Actually, couldn't you map safari version for iOS?

Comment: Why do you need this info anyway? Browser vendor and version should be enough. This type of information shouldn't be available from the browser, it would pose a big risk.

Comment: Why would it be a threat? What difference would it make?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by model version?  You're expecting to see something like "Dell Optiplex 390", or "HP Envy 14-2002ea"?  What about the "no-name" custom rigs that home builders put together?

Comment: Those custom ones could be unknown. And yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: The OS version is in the user agent string. I doubt you can get the model number though.

Comment: The threat is in that this helps in identifying the user / device. Browser strings have a fairly low selectivity, but considering that most PC companies have a lot of formal models of computers, the combination of geographic location, user agent, and hardware could let you identify someone to quite a small group of people.

Comment: @Inerdial Thx **so** much! Also, I don't need the model number. For example, I need maybe 'Mac PowerPC G4 Panther'.

Comment: On Windows machines you *might* be able to instantiate a WMIObject in client-side JavaScript, get that to get the Win32_ComputerSystemProduct and then pass properties back from that.

Comment: @Trevor Tippins Thx! But what about 64-bit

Comment: Same thing. It's just the name of the WMI class.

Comment: @Trevor Tippins so it would be     Win64_ComputerSystemProduct

Comment: No. Just stick with Win32. Read up about WMI Windows Management classes.

Comment: @Trevor Tippins But I'm saying hypothetically if I were to do it it would be that

Comment: No. It's just the same thing, even on a Win64 platform - Win32_ComputerSystemProduct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect that your clients will have Flash installed (95%+ of the world does), you can use a Flash movie to check the flash.system.Capabilities object. It has [lots of information you might be interested in](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html). If you're trying to find it on an iOS machine, then obviously this won't work since it's not going to have Flash on it.