# Find a part of the user agent string

Tags: ajax, user-agent

I was wondering if you could use just a part of the user agent string, for example the firmware, on the web. However, Flash will not work because I need it to work on iOS. This is a follow-up question to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137439/find-the-firmware-in-javascript#comment11485566_9137439). I have tried googling it, but found only Microsoft-specific stuff and stuf that was completely off topic.

Comment: *"Flash will not work."* Hm. Any details you might want to add to that statement?

Comment: @Tomalak I need it to work on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, the value of `navigator.userAgent` tells you what you need. Stick this in your `<head>`:

```
<script>
    alert(navigator.userAgent);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With PHP you can check `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and parse the information from there.

**Just to get more details:**
What languages are you programming in?

**Update**
[Here's](http://blogs.oucs.ox.ac.uk/listeningforimpact/2011/02/16/user-agent-analysis-part-2-name-those-agents/) a link which lists a good amount of User-agent strings and breaks them down: 
Maybe that'll help you in your endeavors.  Seems pretty straight forward, and shows how the headers are constructed (for the most part)

Comment: HTML, PHP, JavaScript, ASP, anything except Flash. I know the mobile Safari user agents show firmware, which is all I need. Yes, I've [looked](http://www.useragentstring.com/).

Comment: Also, is there a way to just get firmware from the user agent?

Comment: Well, I guess I'm confused about your question.  Are you asking us to show you how to parse it?  Maybe I'm not totally getting what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah, kinda. All I need is the firmware.

Comment: This should probably be moved to chat, and also, why don't you edit your original post to show what you have tried?

Comment: Ok how do you do that? Sorry im kinda new.

Answer (score 0):

I figured something like that out.
Just do a user agent (`navigator.useragent`) and then make some variables (model, firmware, device...). Then set values to those variables based on the useragent